# Adding page refresh on dropdown select

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
$("#shipping_method").on("change","select#shipping_method, input[name=shipping_method]", function() { location.reload(); });
```

I am trying to force a page refresh on selection of the dropdown options for shipping in a woocommerce/wordpress website.

No matter where I locate the code, Its not firing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What about `$("body").on("change", "#shipping_method", function() { location.reload(); });`?

Comment: Where would you say is the best place to put the code?

Comment: Before the `</body>` tag in a `document.ready` function if it's not in one already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {

    $("#shipping_method").on("change", function(e) { 
       e.stopPropagation();
       location.reload(); 
    });

});
```

This code will work for what you need, your issue lies in the multitude of JS files somewhere, and it's causing a conflict.

Comment: That was my thought also, why use the second argument in the on-method?

Comment: You use the second one if the first one is a parent class.

Comment: Ive tried adding this, but it doesn't help, I select any of the options and it does a small AJAX animation and then stays the same. No page refresh. Its based on a them called Cosmetico if that helps?

Comment: Do you have the html available?

Comment: You can view the environment live here:

http://topsoillincoln.co.uk

Access with: topsoil / Lincoln1

Comment: What am I looking for exactly?

Comment: Sorry, when a product is in the cart (any product) and you click "My Basket" up top, that is where the shipping selector is being displayed. It is this selector I want to force a refresh on option select otherwise the figure doesn't update :/

Comment: Yeah - I found it.  You have so many js files loading, any one of those could be conflicting with what you are trying to do.  Something appears to be trying to do, well, something.  Have to find out what that is and kill it. Might try to stop the propagation. Ill add that.

Comment: Where would be the best place to put the code? Thanks for your help, by the way :)

Comment: All of your scripts are loaded at the bottom of the page. I would place it there.  WooCommerce has template files that you will need to edit (learn how to extend them, don't edit the core files).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45193/discussion-between-wayners247-and-kelly-j-andrews)

Answer (score 0):

try

`$(document).on("change", "#shipping_method, input[name=shipping_method]", function() { location.reload(); });`

i think the problem is that you use the selector `"#shipping_method` twice.
(not tested)